# How to disable screenshot sharing confirmation on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: screenshot, sharing

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 now each time another application try to get a screenshot the system pops up a message asking me to confirm sharing that screenshot.   It leads to some problems to me, since i use a remote working monitoring app (UpWork Desktop) that takes screenshots every 10mins.

So i would like to know a way to disable this confirmation feature, and come back to regular behavior from Ubuntu 20.04.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: it's possible this is a wayland issue, and switching to xorg should fix it. Not sure if there is a way to disable it while still in wayland though.

Comment: hasn't support on this application finished? [this reference](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Upwork-Team-App-and-Linux-Distro-support/td-p/186451) suggests a work around. I don't think this is a Ubuntu issue....

Comment: Am also facing this issue, when the upwork take screenshot, the Ubuntu also take the screenshot.

Comment: Did you guys manage to fix it?

Comment: Any update here?